# name prop going as undefined

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, redux-form

I am using redux-form and I sent TextField of material-ui as prop to Field of redux-form. But the other properties are going perfectly as expected.

```
<Field
    id="firstName"
    name="firstName"
    floatingLabelText="Username"
    errorText={this.state.firstNameError}
    component={TextInputField}
/>
```

Below code it the TextInputField component

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import TextField from 'material-ui/TextField';
import _noop from 'lodash/noop';

const TextInputField = ({
    hintText,
    id,
    name,
    className,
    defaultValue,
    floatingLabelText,
    errorText,
    onFocus,
    onChange,
    onBlur
}) => {

return (
    <TextField
        hintText={hintText}
        id={id}
        name={name}
        className={className}
        defaultValue={defaultValue}
        floatingLabelText={floatingLabelText}
        errorText={errorText}
        onFocus={onFocus}
        onChange={onChange}
        onBlur={onBlur}
    />
);
};

export default TextInputField;
```

The problem here is name prop is coming as undefined in the place where I used the component.I don't know where this is happening. When I consoled the name prop it is coming as undefined.

Comment: Use the rest operator instead of writing all arguments there. Do a null check  using ternary operator and also make sure name is getting passed into this stateless component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `TextInputField` is supposed to accept `input` and `meta` props according docs. `input` prop has `name` attribute.

From [redux-form docs](https://redux-form.com/7.2.0/docs/api/field.md/#props):

> The props provided by redux-form are divided into input and meta
>   objects.
>
> Any custom props passed to Field will be merged into the props object
>   on the same level as the input and meta objects.

Here is a [quote from input props section](https://redux-form.com/7.2.0/docs/api/field.md/#-code-input-name-string-code-):

> input.name : String When nested in FormSection, returns the name prop
>   prefixed with the FormSection name. Otherwise, returns the name prop
>   that you passed in.

So your component should look like this:

```
const TextInputField = ({
    input: { 
      name,
      onChange,
      onBlur,
      onFocus
    },
    hintText,
    id,
    className,
    defaultValue,
    floatingLabelText,
    errorText
}) => (
  <TextField
      hintText={hintText}
      id={id}
      name={name}
      className={className}
      defaultValue={defaultValue}
      floatingLabelText={floatingLabelText}
      errorText={errorText}
      onFocus={onFocus}
      onChange={onChange}
      onBlur={onBlur}
    />
);
```

or even simpler:

```
const TextInputField = ({ input, meta, ...rest }) => (
  <TextField {...input} {...rest} />
);
```